# Cannot upload a file through webservice that is over 1MB

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2012, web-config

Could some take a look at my web.config and tell me what is wrong with it? I am just not able to upload a file through a remote webservice that is larger than 1MB. I am guessing it has something to do with the attribute settings, but so far I havent had any luck changing the values. Or is it the setting on the host server side that I can't override?

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="CategoryPath" value="QA/ProcessValidation"/>
      </appSettings>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
      </startup>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Authentication" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DocumentManagement" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ContentService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
        </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

EDIT: I have no control for the service on the server side, I am actually only using the WCF and I only have the links to them.

Comment: Perhaps these could help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325(v=vs.110).aspx  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: which error message you get?

Comment: The error is "The remote server returned an unexpected response:(400) Bad Request" .

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear whether the config file you posted is the client config or the server config, but it I'm going to make a semi-educated guess and say it's the client config, and you're using your client to connect to a third-party service.

Without knowing the error message and/or behavior you're seeing, or how you're creating the client in code, there are a few things you can try:

1. Increase the size of the `maxStringContentLength` attribute in the `<readerQuotas>` element.  Right now it is set to the default of 8,192 bytes.
2. If this is the service config, increase the `maxReceivedMessageSize` attribute in the `<binding>` element - right now it is also set to the default of 65536.

The maximum value for both of these attributes is `Int32.MaxValue` - roughly 2GB.  In either case, unless you have an endpoint specified in the config file (which you don't appear to currently) which references the defined binding config (via the `<endpoint>` element's `bindingConfiguration` attribute), you will always get the default values for the endpoint's binding.

So you will need to either make the binding definition the default (by omitting the `name` attribute from the `<binding>` element, or you will need to assign the binding configuration you want to use by using the `bindingConfiguration` attribute on the endpoint, like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding=basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
```

If the service is not under your control, then you will not be able to do much if they have low limits set, as the client cannot modify the service's configuration (and the service cannot modify the client's either).  The configurations are separate, but many parts (binding, security, etc) have to match.

If the above doesn't help, please edit your question to add more info (what error message/behavior are you seeing, is it the client or service config, how are you creating the client, do you have the service config, etc).